# Are running mean plots good indicators for time series convergence?

Tags: time-series, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-chain

I want to know whether a time series has converged. I looked around the MCMC literature (which requires doing something similar -- knowing whether a chain has converged) and found the following:

http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~plam/teaching/methods/convergence/convergence_print.pdf

consider page 13 there, with running mean plot. The idea is to plot the mean up to each iteration and see whether it stabilizes.

First, let me say that I couldn't find a mention of this method anywhere else by googling. When I look for "running mean plots" I mostly get back this deck of slides as a result. So I am not sure if this is indeed a well-known way to check for a MC convergence.

Second, I am quite surprised by this idea. If I am not mistaken, any such plot will converge quite fast, just because of the central limit theorem. We have some distribution, and we sample from it, and draw the mean. Of course it will stabilize, around the mean of the distribution with rather small variance.

I think the idea is that if the MC has not converged, then we will see the mean stabilizing and then changing again after a while when the distribution has moved to a new "station". But it doesn't seem to me like a good way to check for MCMC convergence.

Can someone refer me to some material about this idea of running mean plot, how it can be used to check for a series convergence or at least MC convergence?